# VS Code keyboard shortcut when multiple lines selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I am trying to set up different command to keyboard shortcut when one line is selected and different one when multiple lines. I was trying to find example in default keybindings, but without success. Is there any way to achieve this? What `when` parameter should I use in keybindings file, maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 `when` contexts about selection in the editor

- `editorHasSelection`
- `editorHasMultipleSelections`

If you are looking for a case where the selection is a single selection but multiple lines you are out of luck, the context has no knowledge of what is selected.

---

**Edit**

I have written an extension that fixes this gap in the context for key bindings.

Use [Extra Context](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.extra-context) and it defines `extraContext:editorSelectionHasMultipleLines` to be used with `when` clause.

An example:

In `settings.json`:

```json
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.terminalSingleLine",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": { "text": "echo Single Line\u000D" }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.terminalMultipleLine",
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": { "text": "echo Multiple Lines\u000D" }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

In `keybindings.json`:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k f5", // or any other key combo
    "command": "multiCommand.terminalSingleLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !extraContext:editorSelectionHasMultipleLines"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k f5",
    "command": "multiCommand.terminalMultipleLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && extraContext:editorSelectionHasMultipleLines"
  }
```